# How to Remove outline of input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to debug code, that some other person has written.

I have several input and select fields, all of them with outlines, but different ones.
I did not find any way to change their behaviour and appearance

They look like the following:

How can I change this, so that all look simillar?
I'm using Chrome on MacOS

[Outline Nr1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJCfA.png)
[Outline Nr 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0UjY.png)

Comment: Add the code here.

Comment: You can set the `outline : none;` to remove outline or set with the color to give same outline color. However, if you tried this and this doesn't solve your problem then please share your code.

Comment: It depends on what you are using. For an example some library uses fieldset for that. Are you using raw html css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the stylesheet you're using is the last stylesheet that is applied to make sure your stylesheet's property apply.

Also, make sure you have the highest selector specificity, to be 100% sure, give your input a class like `no-outline` *(it will be better if you put your code here)*

Use the following code:

```
.no-outline:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

If none of this works then just add an `!important` tag in front of the code like

```
.no-outline:focus {
    outline: none; !important
}
```

Though, using the `!important` is **not recommended** unless you have been scratching your head for hours.

And....**if nothing works**, **only if nothing works**, you can set the property inline

```
<input type="text" style="outline: none">
```

Do let me know if you are still confused.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<input style="outline: none" >
```

Or either use this on css file

```
input {
  outline: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set this css in your global css file.

```
input:focus-visible {
  outline: transparent;
}
```